# OS X Mavericks moving from SVN 1.7 to SVN 1.8

Tags: macos, svn

It took me awhile, but I've managed to install SVN 1.8 on my Mac (Mavericks).

But when I do

```
svn --version
```

It's still saying svn 1.7 - which is the previous version installed.

I've checked and it looks like 1.8 is installed in "/usr/local/bin" whereas 1.7 is installed "usr/bin".

I have the following lines in my .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:$PATH
```

I tried renaming "usr/bin/svn" to "usr/bin/svn_", so that when I type svn, it will at least pick up the "usr/local/bin/svn". But it doesn't.

My question is

- What do I do to get 1.8 as the default SVN?
- What's the best way to delete 1.7 safely?

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead of the two lines you had:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
```

You overwrote your path to have `/bin` before `/usr/bin`, that's why the wrong `svn` was picked up. To diagnose this, type

```
which -a svn
```

to list all paths in the order they're resolved.

Comment: Cool! That worked. Now can I delete all the svn* under /usr/bin? (the old 1.7)?

Comment: No, you shouldn't delete system binaries (the same goes for Python, Ruby, and other things OS X ships with). Just use the new one you installed.